# ERRO DE ATRIBUTO EM LAYOUT PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um projeto em Python com o PySimpleGUI usando sg pra layout simples, porém o terminal do PyCharm me retorna o erro de falta de atribuição de valor tentei ir pelo terminal do powershell e cmd e deu o mesmo erro

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class TelaPython:
    def _init_(self):

        layout = [
            [sg.Text('Nome'),sg.Input()],
            [sg.Text('Senha'),sg.Input()],
            [sg.Button('Login')],
            [sg.Button('Cadastrar')],

        ]

        janela = sg.Window(Login).layout(layout)

        self.button, self.values = janela.Read()

    def Iniciar(self):
        print(self.values)

tela = TelaPython()
tela.Iniciar()
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando acessar uma variável da classe que não foi criada.

```py
  self.values = janela.Read()
```

Adicione a variável e tente novamente.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

class TelaPython:
    
    values = ''

    def _init_(self):

        layout = [
            [sg.Text('Nome'),sg.Input()],
            [sg.Text('Senha'),sg.Input()],
            [sg.Button('Login')],
            [sg.Button('Cadastrar')],
        ]

        janela = sg.Window(Login).layout(layout)

        self.button, self.values = janela.Read()

    def Iniciar(self):
        print(self.values)

tela = TelaPython()
tela.Iniciar()
```